# Image loading using Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to show images in the list from `URL` when there are no image URL comes from the service end then I want to show a default image for the particular index. For that I have used `Volley` for image loading in `array adapter`. Now my problem is when I used the default image then images are not showing properly and sometimes it overlap with another image. And when I have not used the default image then it works fine. Here is my code and please suggest me what is wrong with this? Thanks in advance.

Here is my Adapter class,

```
 public class CustomLocalAlertAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LocalListItem>
        implements AppConstants {

    Activity a;
    ViewHolder holder;

    ImageView mImageview;
    private Object mImageLoader;

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        LocalListItem LocalList = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.activity_add_local_all_alert_details, parent,
                    false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.missingTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.missingTitle);
            holder.missingDetails = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.missingDetails);

            holder.missingImage = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.missingImage);
            holder.suspectImage = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.suspectImage);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        String allAlertSuspectDetails = "";

        String allAlertVehicleDetails = "";

        String allAlertPersonDetails = "";

        if (LocalList.title.equalsIgnoreCase("missing_vehicle_report")) {

            allAlertPersonDetails = "";
            allAlertSuspectDetails = "";
            holder.missingTitle.setText("Missing Vehicle");

            allAlertVehicleDetails = "\n" + "Year: " + LocalList.Year + "\n"
                    + "Make: " + LocalList.Make + "\n" + "Model: "
                    + LocalList.Model + "\n" + "Color: " + LocalList.Color
                    + "\n" + "LisencePlateNo: " + LocalList.LisencePlateNo
                    + "\n" + "Vin: " + LocalList.Vin + "\n" + "Place: "
                    + LocalList.Place;

            holder.suspectImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else {

            holder.suspectImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            allAlertVehicleDetails = "";

            holder.missingTitle.setText("Missing Person");

            allAlertPersonDetails = "\n" + "Name: " + LocalList.personName
                    + "\n" + "Height: " + LocalList.height + "\n"
                    + "Unique Mark: " + LocalList.uniqueMark + "\n"
                    + "Last seen: " + LocalList.lastSeen + "\n"
                    + "Date Missing: " + LocalList.dateMissing + "\n"
                    + "Police department: " + LocalList.policeDept + "\n"
                    + "Police dept.phone: " + LocalList.policePhn + "\n" + "\n";

            if (LocalList.suspectName.equalsIgnoreCase("")
                    || LocalList.suspectName.equalsIgnoreCase("null")
                    || LocalList.suspectName.equalsIgnoreCase(" ")) {
                allAlertSuspectDetails = "";

                holder.suspectImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {
                allAlertSuspectDetails = "Suspect name: "
                        + LocalList.suspectName + "\n" + "Vehicle Color: "
                        + LocalList.vehicleColor + "\n" + "Vehicle Year: "
                        + LocalList.vehicleYear + "\n" + "Vehicle Make: "
                        + LocalList.vehicleMake + "\n" + "Vehicle Model: "
                        + LocalList.vehicleModel;
            }
        }


        holder.missingDetails.setText(allAlertVehicleDetails
                + allAlertPersonDetails + allAlertSuspectDetails);

        if (LocalList.title.equalsIgnoreCase("missing_vehicle_report")) {
            if (LocalList.vehicleImg.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(
                    "")) {

                holder.missingImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image_found);
            } else {

                holder.missingImage.setImageUrl(LocalList.vehicleImg,
                        VolleySingleton.getInstance(getContext())
                                .getImageLoader());
            }
        } else {
            if (LocalList.personImage.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(
                    "")) {
                holder.missingImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image_found);

            } else {

                holder.missingImage.setImageUrl(LocalList.personImage,
                        VolleySingleton.getInstance(getContext())
                                .getImageLoader());
            }
            if (LocalList.suspectImage.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(
                    "")) {
                holder.suspectImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image_found);

            } else {

                holder.suspectImage.setImageUrl(LocalList.suspectImage,
                        VolleySingleton.getInstance(getContext())
                                .getImageLoader());
            }

        }

        return convertView;

    }

    public static class ViewHolder {

        TextView missingTitle;
        TextView missingDetails;
        NetworkImageView missingImage;
        NetworkImageView suspectImage;
    }

    public CustomLocalAlertAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<LocalListItem> ListItem, Activity a) {
        super(context, 0, ListItem);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.a = a;

    }

}
```

And here is my VolleySingleton Class,

```
    public class VolleySingleton {
    private static VolleySingleton instance;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private static ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private VolleySingleton(Context context) {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new VolleySingleton(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public static ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoader;
    }
}
```

Comment: Best way - In only one line your problem can resolve. Just pass image link & imageview within adapter. Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView); use this to import liabrary link - https://github.com/square/picasso

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a file MultipartRequest as follows:

```
public class MultipartRequest extends Request<String> {
private MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
private final Response.Listener<String> mListener;
private final File file;
private final HashMap<String, String> params;

public MultipartRequest(String url, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, File file, HashMap<String, String> params)
{
    super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);

    mListener = listener;
    this.file = file;
    this.params = params;
    buildMultipartEntity();
    buildMultipartEntity2();

}



private void buildMultipartEntity()
{
    entity.addBinaryBody(KEY_IMAGE, file, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), file.getName());
    entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    entity.setLaxMode().setBoundary("xx").setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    try
    {
        for ( String key : params.keySet() ) {
            entity.addPart(key, new StringBody(params.get(key)));
        }
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        VolleyLog.e("UnsupportedEncodingException");
    }
}

@Override
public String getBodyContentType()
{
    return entity.build().getContentType().getValue();
}
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> headers = super.getHeaders();

    if (headers == null
            || headers.equals(Collections.emptyMap())) {
        headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }

    headers.put("Accept", "application/json");

    return headers;
}

@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try
    {
        entity.build().writeTo(bos);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream");
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
/**
 * copied from Android StringRequest class
 */
@Override
protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    String parsed;
    try {
        parsed = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        parsed = new String(response.data);
    }
    return Response.success(parsed, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
    mListener.onResponse(response);
}}
```

In your activity just make Multipart Request as follows:

```
 public void uploadImage()
{
    try {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

           HashMap params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        MultipartRequest sr = new MultipartRequest( UPLOAD_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if ((pDialog != null) && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
                Log.d("file", f + "");
                Log.d("", ".......response====" + response.toString());

                ////////
                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                    String serverCode = object.getString("code");
                    if (serverCode.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {

                    }
                    if (serverCode.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        try {

                            if ("1".equals(serverCode)) {
                                JSONObject object1 = object.getJSONObject("data");

                            }
                        }
```